# asp.net: Handling form data in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, forms, visual-studio-2010, runat

Climbing the learning curve for creating asp.net webform pages with Visual Studio 2010 (VB).

I had written a fairly complicated .aspx page with form controls, including textboxes and buttons, etc. I never thought to place the form controls inside a `<form>` block. Instead, all the controls include the "runat" directive; for example, `<asp:textbox id="txtUserName" runat="server">` etc. In the codebehind I access the data with `strUserName = txtUserName.text`. This seems to work just fine.

Now, though, I received some form pages from our contracted "professional" web developer wherein the form code is all enclosed in a `<form runat="server">`block, and none of the controls include the `runat` directive. Accessing the data from these controls is a little different: It uses the `<input type="text name="txtUserName" id="txtUserName" />` method, and accessing the data in the codebehind 
is `strUserName = Request.Form("txtUserName").ToString`.

My method seems to work fine, but I am wondering if there is a difference in behavior or reliability between my method and his. Even though my way works, am I doing it wrong?

Mine is based on online research I have done to learn this stuff, and I don't remember seeing anything that looked like his. However, just today I see places that are saying that on .aspx pages, form controls MUST be enclosed in a `<form>` block (i.e., [this page at w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/ASPnet/aspnet_forms.asp)).

Can anyone clarify this for me?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Without form how do you sumbit data on server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not doing it incorrectly (you're using my preferred approach) but your inputs should still be in an enclosing Form tag.

He's using HtmlControls (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls namespace) and you're using web controls (System.Web.UI.WebControls.) Your controls provide better functionality on the server (viewstate and accessing via server code) and his approach is lighter weight.

Comment: That makes sense considering the page he wrote for us was pretty extensive. It's our company's online store. It's not exactly a state-of-the-art ecommerce site, it only sends the customer's order via an email to our sales department, so it doesn't process credit cards and such; but mine is considerably less complicated, though it does use update  panels. Thanks!

Comment: In you case you will need a form tag else your asp.net page will throw errors when you put any asp.net Controls. Is your page using a MasterPage? In that case the form will be in MasterPage and not your .aspx page.

Comment: The page from our contracted web developer came only with the main aspx page and the CS codebehind. Do you recommend moving the form to the master page? Would there be any benefit to that? As it is, it is still throwing a few errors inside Visual Studio, and I am having to iron those out. It's very difficult to second-guess another programmer.

Comment: Without understanding your specific structure.. I personally would recommend against placing the form tag in a master page without a specific app/structure reason to do so.